# How do I change font sizes in Heaps?

Tags: haxe

I'm currently coding in Haxe with Heaps and was checking on how to display text. One thing I want to do is give different font sizes to different texts. Naturally, I declared two Font instances and resized one of them. However, both texts are resized and I cannot manage to have them resize independently. How should I resize font sizes in Heaps?

```
class Main extends hxd.App{
    override function init(){
       var font : h2d.Font = hxd.res.DefaultFont.get();
       var font2 : h2d.Font = hxd.res.DefaultFont.get();
       font2.resizeTo(23);

       var tf = new h2d.Text(font);
       var tf2 = new h2d.Text(font2);

       tf.text = "Hello World\nHeaps is great!";
       tf.textColor = 0x00FF00;
       tf.x = 100;
       tf.y = 100;
       tf.textAlign = Center;

       tf2.text = "Hello World\nHeaps is great!";
       tf2.textColor = 0x00FF00;
       tf2.x = 300;
       tf2.y = 300;
       tf2.textAlign = Center;


       s2d.addChild(tf);
       s2d.addChild(tf2);

    static function main(){
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach taken does not work because [DefaultFont](https://github.com/HeapsIO/heaps/blob/master/hxd/res/DefaultFont.hx).get() caches the result.

You could either:

- Copy the second font by doing `var font2 : h2d.Font = font.clone()` so that it gets its own properties.
- Adjust `scaleX` and `scaleY` of Text.